# I'm having raycasting issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I'm currently trying to have a raycast detect the player caracter to have an event happen when a specific key is pressed here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class action: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float dist;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D down = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, dist);
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) == true && down.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("hi");
        }  
    }
}
```

I'm basicly trying to make a small raycast,which is why I place a distance instead of letting it go infinitely, and have it so if the raycast is triggered and the player presses z the event happens(which for now is the debug console), but all it does now is triggers whenever I press z no matter where the player caracter is. I tried drawing the raycast but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for that is that the raycast is hitting the object containning the script it self and so the collider is allways non null try adding a LayerMask that differs from the GameObject's Layer

**so it's something like this :**

```
    RaycastHit2D down = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up, 
    dist , 1 << /*The Target's Layer*/);
```

**You can find the layer in the up left corner of your inspector when you click on a GameObject**

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a [`LayerMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) on the `down`. The Raycast must be colliding with the player's Collider. In case you don't know what LayerMask is.

***LayerMask** can be used to detect Raycast that collides with only the objects with that layer on it.*

The ayer Dropdown, on each GameObject, refers to the layer of the object as shown:

[image: Image showing LayerMask In Unity GameEngine]

Head to the Unity Documentation for [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want make raycast when press Z will be good to do it in time press:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{       
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)){            
        RaycastDown()
    }  
}

private void RaycastDown()
{
    Debug.Log("Player position: " + transform.position);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, 
    Vector2.down, dist);
    if(hit.collider != null){
        Debug.Log($"Hit object: {hit.transform.name}" );
    }
}
```

And about issue, make sure that hit object has a collider or collider is active.
Possibly problem in raycast direction. To check it, use [Debug.DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html), it`s help you to visualize a ray which you draw